# Правильный выбор числа местоимения

Tags: согласование, однородные-члены, единственное-множественное-число, местоимения

Зашёл спор, как правильно написать:
***Чей*** (или ***чьи***) *тогда взгляд и улыбка будут освещать мне путь?*

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно выбрать число местоимения. Если есть возможность, то нужна ссылка на правило.

Comment: http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/3052-soglasovanie-opredeleniy-opredelyaemyim-56789.html

Answer (score 3):

Если определение [чей] относится к двум существительным, имеющим форму единственного числа и выступающим в роли однородных членов [взгляд, улыбка — подлежащие], то оно может стоять и в единственном, и во множественном числе.

**Если по контексту ясно**, что определение относится не только к ближайшему существительному, но и к последующему (то есть речь идет об одном человеке), то оно ставится единственном числе:

***Чей*** тогда взгляд и улыбка будут освещать мне путь?
Дикий гусь и утка прилетели первыми (Тургенев); необыкновенный шум и говор (Пушкин).

[Согласование определений с определяемым словом](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/part-167.htm)

P.S. Если в предложении речь идет о разных людях (что маловероятно) или необходимо сделать дополнительный смысловой акцент, то можно написать так:
*Чей тогда взгляд и чья улыбка будут освещать мне путь?*